# How do I make an app continue where it left off instead of opening the Main activity when the icon is clicked?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-launcher, android-navigation

I'm working on my first app. If a user navigates from my main activity to another (Main > A) and then puts the app in the background and clicks the launcher, it launches into Main instead of resuming activity A. The user can then `back` to A, so the stack is Main > A > Main. I want the launcher to merely resume where the user was in activity A instead of starting a new Main activity. How do I control this?

Answer (score 0):

"it launches into Main instead of resuming activity A. The user can then back to A, so the stack is Main > A > Main "

this is definatly wrong, your stack know is Main>A and please provide code. maybe the android destroy your activity because of low memory or you call somewhere finish() method.